# Facebook instant article header image

Tags: wordpress, facebook-instant-articles

I am trying to automatically display an image inside the header of a Facebook instant article. I'm using Wordpress default RSS feed. Is there a way to automatically append the featured image of the post to the instant article header or you should always edit the markup from the publishing tools? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Instant Article WP Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/fb-instant-articles/)

It automatically generates feed located at /feed/instant-articles.

Instant articles from this feed will have header image from post's "feature image".